# Django restframework, Authentication credentials were not provided, knox-tokenauthentication

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-rest-knox

I took a tutorial in Redox and Django from youtube from Traversy Media.
I follow along with the tutorial and now I don't know were it curshed.

```
curl http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login/ -d \
'{"username": "Tom", "password": "PassWord@321"}' \
-H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST
```

By doing so I need to get user and the corresponding token but instead I'm getting

```
{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

What all I did =>

```
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'leads',
    'rest_framework',
    'frontend',
    'accounts',
    'knox',
    'django.contrib.admin', 
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": ("knox.auth.TokenAuthentication", ),
}
```

```
# serializers.py

class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
   username = serializers.CharField()
   password = serializers.CharField()

   def validate(self, data):
      user = authenticate(**data)
      if user and user.is_active:
         return user
      raise serializers.ValidationError("Incorrect Credentials")
```

```
# api.py

class LoginAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
   serializer_class = LoginSerializer

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      serializer = self.get_serializer(data = request.data)
      serializer.is_valid(raise_exception = True)
      user = serializer.validated_data
      _, token = AuthToken.objects.create(user)
      return Response({
         "user": UserSerializer(user, context = self.get_serializer_context()).data,
         "token": token
      })
```

```
# leadmanager/urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path("api/auth/", include("accounts.urls")),
]

# accounts/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
   path("login/", LoginAPI.as_view()),
]
```

I don't know were it crushed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add this code

```
class LoginAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
   serializer_class = LoginSerializer
   permission_classes = () # empty tuple 

   ...........
```

Here you need to override `permission_classes` for `LoginAPI` view as `permission_classes` are responsible to check whether the request is authenticated. As `LoginAPI` is exposed for all users that View has no permission check.